# "Подвал" для сайта не получается реализовать для всех браузеров

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, уважаемое сообщество!

Существует проблема на сайте с "подвалом" нужный блок не хочет везде жестко привязываться к низу страницы так, что бы не перекрывал основной блок с контентом. На IE работает, в других привязан к разрешению экрана. Вот код стиля:

```
footer {position:relative; height:40; bottom:-40; padding-bottom:50;  padding-left:127; text-decoration:none; list-style:none;}

footer ul {list-style:none;}

footer A:link {color:gainsboro; display:inherit; text-decoration: none;}
footer A:visited {color:gainsboro; display:inherit; text-decoration: none;}
footer A:hover {color:orange; display:inherit; text-decoration: none;}
```

Вот листинг

```
<body style="//text-decoration:none;">
  <div id="header"><img src="../img/header2.png"> </div>
  <div class="info">
    <ul class="h">
      <li style="margin-left:30px; //margin-left:50px; padding-top:0;"> content </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li class="text" style="text-align:justify; "> content2 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<?php include "inc/menu.php"; ?>
  <div id="banner"></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <ul>
      <li><font color="gainsboro" size="5"> | <font color="gainsboro" size="2"><font color="gainsboro" size="5"> | </font> 2010-2012<font color="gainsboro" size="5"> | </font> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но вроде позицию лучше в Абсолюте указать для футера :) 

Comment: а что будет с Вашим абсолютно позиционированным футером, если, допустим, изменить разрешение экрана?....или, если зернистость экрана будет другой?)))

Comment: Таки ошибаетесь!

Comment: Нужно приводить не CSS а HTML - CSS условно приведенному HTML напишут, минута дела!

Comment: в именно?в каком из двух пунктов?

Comment: @LeD4eG мой коммент был адресован автору ответа!

Answer (score 5):

```
#all-but-footer { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
#all-but-footer #inner { margin-bottom: 40px; }
#footer { height: 40px; margin-top: -40px; }
```

Ну так правильно. Присмотритесь к коду выше: он предполагает примерно такое:

```
<div id="all-but-footer"><!-- это блок, который всегда на весь экран -->
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <!-- и так далее, весь контент здесь -->
  </div><!-- здесь 40px для футера -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <!-- а здесь футер, который благодаря margin-top == -height накладывается на предыдущий блок -->
</div>
```

Comment: не помогло, встал как вкопанный после absolute блоков, а у меня в центре relative

Comment: @bros575, раз встал, как вкопанный, может измените существенно масштаб страницы и посмотрите что у вас получится. но, если у Вас под фразой "в центре" имеется в виду какой-то контейнер, который содержит весь контент страницы (и футер находится там же), тогда Вам надо бы разобраться что означает `position: relative` и абсолютное позиционирование действительно могло помочь.

Comment: Тут может еще быть известный глюк с высотой. При разных доктайпах полная высота записывается либо как `'height: 100%;'` либо `'min-height: 100%: height: auto;'` либо `'min-height: 100%; height: 100%;'`. То есть, в вашем случае может основной блок не растягиваться на всю высоту. Было бы больше времени - я бы накидал модельку. Попробуйте сами - создайте пустой html с кучей контента, поставьте блокам `'border: #0f0 1px solid;'` и играйтесь с высотой. Как получится - переносите. Да, имейте в виду, что padding влияет на высоту (у вас футер 90px).

Comment: @Sh4dow на мое мнение неверная html разметка, для чего ТС и должен был выложить html.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, не пойму что делать )))

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте вот это: [Как прижать футер (подвал) к низу](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/karkas-verstki/podval-k-nizu.html).
Думаю,поможет. Только читайте внимательно. Там есть метод №2 (решение с абсолютным позиционированием). Мне он больше по душе.

Comment: Хм а я не это же написал?) Но вообще да, там демка есть, это хорошо.

Comment: благодарю всех за содействие! справился, добавил распорку. Статья что надо!